# How do I move Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Using Highcharts I have managed to get two basic gauges displaying random data.
This is dependent though on a big chunk of a javascript function in my main code. It also uses a further function to generate a random result.  I wish to move it to an external file, how do I go about this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>

        <title>2 gauge</title>

    <!--  start of .js-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(function() {
            $('#chart-A').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'gauge',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Gauge1'
                    },
                    pane: {
                        startAngle: -150,
                        endAngle: 150,
                    },
                    // the value axis
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 200,
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [1]
                    }]
                },
                // Add some life
                function(chart) {
                    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                                newVal,
                                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

                            newVal = point.y + inc;
                            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                                newVal = point.y - inc;
                            }

                            point.update(newVal);

                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });


            $('#chart-B').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'gauge',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Gauge2'
                    },
                    pane: {
                        startAngle: -150,
                        endAngle: 150,
                    },
                    // the value axis
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [1]
                    }]
                },
                // Add some life
                function(chart) {
                    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var point = chart.series[0].points[0], 
                                    newVal, 
                                    inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);
                                newVal = point.y + inc;

                            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
                                newVal = point.y - inc;
                            }
                                point.update(newVal);
                            }, 500);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });

        </script>
    <!--  end of .js-->

    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                Couple of random guages
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="chart-A" class="chart"></div>
                <div id="chart-B" class="chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see it uses a lot of space and is repeated twice, and it used a further function that I would like to seperate out.

Yours Simon M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: define the functions in a `.js` file and then import them into the html using a script tag,

```
<script src="/js/myFile.js"></script>
```

However, if your application grows, this will not be easy. Thus you can use a frontend framework like React, Vue or Angular for that.

Or you can use the most modern approach, webcomponents. (So that the output is not an overkill). You can use the Polymer framework to build webcomponents.

The power of webcomponents is that you can use them anywhere despite of the framework, once implemented.

Comment: Thankyou Pubudu, what you are describing is well beyond me yet, I'm still on page one of JS!

Answer (score 1):

Move your js code in an external file `myjscode.js`

and import it in your html:

```
<script src="myjscode.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just cut and paste ALL of the code between <!--  start of .js--> /<!--  end of .js--> in to a new file called "myjscode.js"? Then invoke it with <script src="myjscode.js"></script>, with out any modification? And to use the random number bit I can do the same from within the new .js?

Comment: just the code between `<script type="text/javascript">`and `<script>`. Not familiar with the `highcharts` library you are using but if everything works now, it will work with the changes

Answer (score 0):

Both what Pubudu and Sebastien are the correct answers, I found that Dreamweaver can do it for you.

Tools - Externalize JavaScript.

Yours Simon M.